# Yahoo i chart API not working

Tags: api, yahoo

Yahoo i chart API is not working, i used it two days back, but now its returning page not found error. Please help me in this, below is the link

I am not sure if something is wrong on framing link, i have tried loading the page with different symbols, but still the problem persist

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=EFUT&a=01&b=04&c=2015&d=01&e=14&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesn't work because you are fetching for smaller time frame, just replace "c=2015" to "c=2014"

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=EFUT&a=01&b=04&c=2014&d=01&e=14&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv - works